# Display records based on selected value from dropdown

Tags: php

A user searches a page called search.php, the results of the search are displayed on another page called results.

This works quite well.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  $fields = array(
      'projectTitle' => array('field' => 'b.BidTitle', 'searchType' => 'like'),
      'BidType' => array('field' => 'b.BidType', 'searchType' => 'equal'),
      'BidStatus' => array('field' => 'b.BidStatus', 'searchType' => 'equal'),
      'department' => array('field' => 'b.Department', 'searchType' => 'equal'),
      'bidId' => array('field' => 'b.BidID', 'searchType' => 'equal'),
      'bidDate' => array('field' => 'b.BidDate', 'searchType' => 'equal'),
      'dueDate' => array('field' => 'b.DueDate', 'searchType' => 'equal')

  );

  $where = array();
  foreach($fields as $fieldPost => $field) {
      if(isset($_POST[$fieldPost]) && strlen($_POST[$fieldPost]) > 0) {
          if($field['searchType'] == 'like') {
              $where[] = "".$field['field']." LIKE '%" . ms_escape_string($_POST[$fieldPost]) . "%'";
          } else {
              $where[] = "".$field['field']." = '" . ms_escape_string($_POST[$fieldPost]) . "'";
          }
      }
  }
     $sql = "Select b.ID,convert(char(10),b.BidDate,101) BidDate,convert(char(10),
            b.DueDate,101)DueDate,b.BidTitle,b.DueTime,b.BidID,BidIDFile,
            d.Department,b.BidType,CASE WHEN b.AwardDate ='01/01/1900' Then NULL ELSe convert(char(10),b.AwardDate,101)END AS AwardDate,
            convert(char(10),b.LastUpdate,101) LastUpdate,s.Status
            FROM bids b inner join dept d on b.Department=d.DeptID inner join Status s on b.BidStatus=s.StatusId " . ( count($where) > 0 ? " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where) : "" );
  //echo $sql;
    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );

    $num_rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
```

Now, I have the following dropdown values generated from View --> Source.

```
<select name="SType">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Bid" name="Bid">Bid[2]</option>
  <option value="Lib CM" name="Library CM">Lib CM[23]</option>
  <option value="Quote" name="Quote">Quote[20]</option>
  <option value="RFP" name="RFP">RFP[2]</option>
  <option value="Removed" name="Removed">Removed[29]</option>
  <option value="Archived" name="Archived">Archived[4501]</option>
  <option value="Awarded" name="Awarded">Awarded[40]</option>
  <option value="Open" name="Open">Open[47]</option>
  <option value="Closed" name="Closed">Closed[11]</option>
  <option value="Under Review" name="Under Review">Under Review[126]</option>
  <option value="Cancelled" name="Cancelled">Cancelled[64]</option>
</select>
```

This dropdown also resides on search.php page and was dynamically populated with records from sql server db using php.

As with the code above, when a user selects a value from the dropdown, we would like to display results of records associated with value selected from the dropdown.

I attempted to integrate the below code with the code above but it is not giving me the result I expected. The expected result is only result associated with dropdown value.

For instance, Bid has two records. When a user selects bid from the dropdown, we would expect to see only two records displayed.

Instead sevaral records not related to bid are being displayed as well.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
//If value matches dropdown value, then display records associated with dropdown value
if(isset($_REQUEST['Solicitations'])){
    if($_GET['Solicitations'] == "Bid"){
    $result = "SELECT * FROM bids where BidStatus = 1 and BidType = 'Bid' ORDER BY title";
    $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
    }
  }
```

Many thanks for all help I receive here.

Comment: `$_REQUEST['Solicitations']` needs to be `$_REQUEST['SType']` since you're using `<select name="SType">` - Same thing for `$_GET['Solicitations']` => `$_GET['SType']`

Comment: Also, `<option>` do not hold name attributes, `<select>` does. Just use the values from it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thanks.

The issue though is that it is still displaying records from various other solicitation types other than just the one you passed to it.

In this case, I would have loved to see only results associated with those 2 bids but that is not working out well.